# Browserify does not work - why?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have the following code that I browserify to bundle.js, that I include (before loading any other .js file) on my front-end. The file I browserify is simply this this:

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
```

I then call authorize() on this variable, in the next file that is included on the front-end, but I get an error saying firebase is not defined?

Comment: Have you ever used Browserify before? :)

Comment: No lol I am just trying to get some stuff work

Comment: Do you want some explanations?

Comment: Definitely yes!

Answer (score 2):

**Browserify** is a module bundler that enables you to use **CommonJS** (Node) modules in your browser. This implies that your project must follow **CommonJS** conventions to export (`exports`, `module.exports`) and import (`require`) modules. Here is a basic example:

**Your module (*module.js*)**

```
var foo = function () {
  console.log('Foo');
};

var bar = function () {
  console.log('Bar');
};

module.exports = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar
};
```

**Your entry point (*main.js*)**

```
var module = require('./module');

module.foo(); // Foo
module.bar(); // Bar
```

This code will work out-of-the-box with Node, but your browser cannot interpret it. This is where Browserify is useful...

When you run the command `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` on your entry point, Browserify traverses all your dependencies (here `module.js`) and loads them in a bundle. This bundle is usable in your browser, so you can now load it in a script tag:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still unclear to be honest. Why am I getting the error? I did everything correctly, didn't I?

Comment: I think your dependencies are incorrectly managed. In your question, you say that you include `bundle.js` "before loading any other .js file". But if you use Browserify, you are supposed to organize your project around modules and avoid independent JS script files...

Comment: Moreover, when you say "I then call authorize() on this variable, in the next file that is included on the front-end", I suspect that you are trying to access your variable from a simple JS script file. This will not work because a Browserify bundle is like a big module which has its own scope. It is strictly encapsulated in a function.

Comment: I just need access to the firebase module (that's all). How would I go about that?

Comment: oh got it! so I need to put all my code inside the bundle's function, at least the one I want ran, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go! :) Your sources will still have several script files (your modules...), but your bundle will contain all your code. This is very efficient because all your JavaScript will be loaded with only one HTTP request.