# Browserify - cannot find module

Tags: javascript

I have one-line long file that I browserified:

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
```

I then try to call functions on this variable (in the bundle.js file). But when I try to load up, I get the error message 'cannot find module 'firebase''. How is that possible? It is supposed to find the modules and load them in automatically, right?

Comment: You asked the same question 10 hours ago: [Browserify does not work - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748190/browserify-does-not-work-why)

Answer (score -1):

Missing browserify-shim I just entered this line in the prompt
 Please try it. may be works fine.

```
 npm install browserify-shim
```

Also see the document: https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist/issues/40

Comment: I don't think that's the solution

Comment: I saw that link. And?